# Adding a new row to Knockout ObservableArray without values

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to push a new row to an observable array without any values to show two dropdowns and a few text boxes.  This for a timesheet.  I am not too sure how I can replicate this in a fiddle.

When I comment out the push part the console log shows the original values, which is what I do not want.  Is need to add a new row without any values, somewhere I am missing something or doing something wrong.

**Part of the view model**

```
    vmTimesheets = function () {
       var self = this;
       self.TimesheetList = ko.observableArray([]);
       self.TimeSheetRows = ko.observableArray([]);
       self.TimeSheetHeader = ko.observableArray([]);
       self.ProjectList = ko.observableArray([]); // this is filled through an ajax call
       self.ActivityList = ko.observableArray([]);   // this is filled through an ajax call

    self.GetTimesheets = function () {
       // get the ajax data from the server    
[{"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TimeSheetID":1,"WeekNo":23,"ProjectID":1,"ActivityID":1,"RowUniqueNo":"1433070236953",
"TimesheetColumns":[{"ColTimeSheetID":1,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"5/31/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":0,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":false,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":2,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/1/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":8,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":true,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":3,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/2/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":8,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":true,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":4,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/3/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":0,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":true,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":6,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/4/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":0,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":true,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":7,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/5/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":0,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":true,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":8,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/6/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":0,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":false,"IsEnabled":false}]}]"
    }    

//TimeSheetHeader just has the dates of the current week.
    self.AddRow = function () {

        var jsondata = ""
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(objvmTimesheets.TimeSheetHeader(), function (item) {

            jsondata = ko.toJSON(objvmTimesheets.TimeSheetRows, ['RowTimeSheetID', 'TimeSheetID', , 'ProjectID', 'ActivityID',
        'RowUniqueNo', 'TimesheetColumns', 'ColTimeSheetID', 'RowTimeSheetID', 'TMTypeID', 'WorkDay', 'DayHours',
            'DayComments', 'IsWeekday', 'IsEnabled']);
        });
        objvmTimesheets.TimeSheetRows.push(ko.mapping.fromJSON(JSON.parse(jsondata))); // I assume this should show a new row but it 
     }
}
```

**Template**

```
<script type="text/html" id="TimesheetListTmpl">

<tr class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">


    <td >
    <select id="Projects" name="Project" class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.ProjectList, optionsText: 'ProjectName', optionsValue: 'ProjectID', value: ProjectID, optionsCaption: 'Select',valueAllowUnset: true">
                        </select>
    </td>
     <td >
    <select id="Activity" name="Activity" class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.ActivityList, optionsText: 'Activity', optionsValue: 'ActivityID', value: ActivityID, optionsCaption: 'Select',valueAllowUnset: true">
                        </select>
    </td>

     <!-- ko foreach : TimesheetColumns -->
    <td>
    <input style="width:60px" type="text" data-bind="value:DayHours,attr:{id: 'DayHours' + ':' + $index() + $parentContext.$index()},enable:IsWeekday "><span style="padding-left:5px"><a href="#" title='Add Comment'" data-bind="attr:{id: 'DayHours' + ':' + $index() + $parentContext.$index()},visible:IsWeekday " >+</a></span>


    </td>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>

</script>
```

**Error that I get**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "options: function
>   (){return $root.ProjectList }" Message: ProjectID is not defined

**EDIT1**

After adding a row even though I get that error in the console I try to see what is added in the observable I see the second row as a function where as the first one is just a object.
     objvmTimesheets.TimeSheetRows()

The output shows like this.  The Object has the items mapped where as function c() is nothing.  So I am assuming the items to be mapped.

`[Object, c()]`

**Edit 2**

Here is fiddle which I get the same error

[Fiddle with the same error](http://jsfiddle.net/adriandcosta/t3o71oy4/1/)

**Working Code**

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriandcosta/t3o71oy4/5/)**

I finally got this to work.  Below is my working code. I will also update the fiddle so it would be helpful for reference later/

```
vmTimesheets = function () {
       var self = this;
       self.TimesheetList = ko.observableArray([]);
       self.TimeSheetRows = ko.observableArray([]);
       self.TimeSheetHeader = ko.observableArray([]);
       self.ProjectList = ko.observableArray([]); // this is filled through an ajax call
       self.ActivityList = ko.observableArray([]);   // this is filled through an ajax call

    self.GetTimesheets = function () {
       // get the ajax data from the server    
[{"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TimeSheetID":1,"WeekNo":23,"ProjectID":1,"ActivityID":1,"RowUniqueNo":"1433070236953",
"TimesheetColumns":[{"ColTimeSheetID":1,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"5/31/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":0,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":false,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":2,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/1/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":8,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":true,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":3,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/2/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":8,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":true,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":4,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/3/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":0,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":true,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":6,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/4/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":0,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":true,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":7,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/5/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":0,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":true,"IsEnabled":false},{"ColTimeSheetID":8,"RowTimeSheetID":1,"TMTypeID":0,"WorkDay":"6/6/2015 12:00:00 AM","DayHours":0,"DayComments":"","IsWeekday":false,"IsEnabled":false}]}]"
    }    

  self.AddTimeSheetRows = function () {
        objvmTimesheets.objvmAddTimeSheetRow.AddRow();
    }

vmAddTimesheetRows = function () {
        var self = this
        self.RowTimeSheetID = ko.observable("");
        self.TimeSheetID = ko.observable("");
        self.RowUniqueNo = ko.observable("");
        self.WeekNo = ko.observable("");

        self.ProjectID = ko.observable("");
        self.ActivityID = ko.observable("");
        self.TimesheetColumns = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.AddRow = function () {
            objvmTimesheets.objvmAddTimeSheetRow.TimesheetColumns.removeAll();
            var kojsondata = "";
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(objvmTimesheets.TimeSheetHeader(), function (item) {
                objvmTimesheets.objvmTimeSheetColumns.WorkDay(item.TSDate);
                objvmTimesheets.objvmTimeSheetColumns.IsWeekday(item.IsWeekday());
                kojsondata = ko.toJSON(objvmTimesheets.objvmTimeSheetColumns, ['ColTimeSheetID', 'RowTimeSheetID', 'WorkDay', 'DayHours', 'DayComments', 'IsWeekday']);

                objvmTimesheets.objvmAddTimeSheetRow.TimesheetColumns.push(JSON.parse(kojsondata));

            });
            objvmTimesheets.objvmAddTimeSheetRow.RowUniqueNo(moment().toDate().getTime())

            var jsondata = ko.toJSON(objvmTimesheets.objvmAddTimeSheetRow, ['RowTimeSheetID', 'TimeSheetID', 'WeekNo', 'ProjectID', 'ActivityID',
        'RowUniqueNo', 'TimesheetColumns', 'ColTimeSheetID', 'RowTimeSheetID', 'WorkDay', 'DayHours', 'DayComments', 'IsWeekday']);
            objvmTimesheets.TimeSheetRows.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(jsondata)));



        }

    };  // End Timesheet Rows view model
    self.objvmAddTimeSheetRow = new vmAddTimesheetRows();


vmAddTimesheetColumns = function () {

        var self = this;
        self.ColTimeSheetID = ko.observable("");
        self.RowTimeSheetID = ko.observable("");
        self.WorkDay = ko.observable("");
        self.DayHours = ko.observable("");
        self.DayComments = ko.observable("");
        self.IsWeekday = ko.observable(true);


    };  // End Timesheet Rows view model
    self.objvmTimeSheetColumns = new vmAddTimesheetColumns();
}; End of Main View Model
```

Comment: What it is complaining about is that your ProjectList variable has an entry with no ProjectID member.

Comment: That is what I am not able to figure out

Comment: I commented out both the dropdowns from the template now I get this error ``Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return TimesheetColumns }"
Message: TimesheetColumns is not defined``

Comment: Is your template used in a foreach? What variable is bound there?

Comment: Yes it is, in the <select...., BTW I updated by question

Comment: The result of `ko.mapping.fromJSON` is going to be an observable or observableArray. You should probably check the state of what you've got at each stage leading up to the push. At the very least, you should be pushing the *contents* of the result of the `ko.mapping.fromJSON`.

Comment: @Adrian TimesheetColumns must be a an ObservableArray which will contain the JSON attributes you want to parse

Comment: @Adrian setup a fiddle it will be easy to figure out . cheers

Comment: @RoyJ the Columns is a nested json of Rows.  So I think I cannot push a nest json into an observablearray, might have to use a foreach

Comment: I have added a fiddle which has the same error

Comment: @RoyJ and others I finally got this to work.  I added the working code